# Debug Tizen wereable web in device using IDE and Samsung accessory framework

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-mobile-sdk

i don't find any way for debug a wereable tizen web app that uses Samsung Accessory Framework for connect with Galaxy phones, i use the emulator way and it works but i need also debug in real devices but when a Gear S2 connects with a Galaxy phone using Gear Manager the wifi connection of my Gear is lost because it automatically uses the wifi of the phone through bluetooth, so i can't debug apps using Tizen IDE because the gear needs to have an IP direction.

there is any way for connect my Tizen IDE with gear s2 devices that are already connected with Galaxy phones? there is a way for disable automatic wifi disconnection when the gear is connected with a phone?

Answer (score 1):

Connect your devices (phone and wearable) with your home/office router directly (you can connect your Gear S2 directly with router).

According to this link http://www.tizenexperts.com/2015/12/how-to-deploy-to-gear-s2-smartwatch/, the connection between PC and Device over WiFi is not stable. For a slightly better experience increase the screen time out of GS2 while debugging so that chances of getting disconnected will be a bit reduced.

Comment: you don't understand my question, my problem is about debugging in Gear S2 devices that needs to be connected with Gear Manager and the same time with tizen IDE, Gear S2 can only be debuged using WiFi and when you connect it with Gear Manager then the WiFi is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Would you check your Gear S2 software version?
Why don't you try to update software version in the Gear Manager?

In initial version, there is the problem you mentioned but it is solved by software updated.

Just now, i tested that SDK connect S2 by wifi and Galexy connect S2 by BT concurrently. It's fine, it works well. :)

You can update your gear S2 software in the Gear Manager > Settings > Gear info > Gear Software Update.

Good luck!
Bye.